# What is the fastest way to remove duplicate numbers in an array for ES5 and below with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates, reduce

As the title says, I'm only interested in vanilla JS upto ES5. And the array to be sorted (a) contains only non-negative integers (0,1,2,3...). Also the order does not matter.

I'm not sure whether filter,reduce, or for loop is faster:

## 1) filter

```
uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```

## 2) reduce

```
var unique = a.reduce(function(reduceArray,currentValue){
    if (reduceArray.indexOf(currentValue) < 0 ) reduceArray.push(currentValue);
    return reduceArray;
  },[]);
```

## 3) for

```
var hash   = [],
    unique = [];
for (var i= 0, len = a.length; i<len; i++) {
   if (!hash[a[i]]) {
      unique.push(a[i]);
   }
   hash[a[i]] = true; 
}
```

I think the for-loop has the best performance. My reasoning:

1. the for loop runs in O(n)
2. Function calls in JS are expensive. filter and reduce are calling a function. The for loop doesn't

Is my reasoning ok? is there a more efficient way to remove duplicates?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: "performance is highly sensitive to things like what hardware you are using" <-- a good algo on a poor hardware can still trump a bad algo on a good hardware.

Comment: Does order of elements matter to you?

Comment: Order does not matter. @alexeibs

Comment: you problem is the use of indexOf. that makes bad perfomance, because for every item, the array has to be searched for the index.

Comment: You can't really compare the first two to the third. The first two work with any arbitrary value, that is at the very least in same way comparable. Whereas, the third option requires the value to be *stringify-able*.

Comment: First of all please correct the `if (hash[a[i]]) {` line to `if (!hash[a[i]]) {` so that it filters out the dupes. Ok the for loop is fast but in  your example you are using an array for the hash which limits your array items to positive integers. To lift this limitation you need a proper object or Map object hash and Object.keys() or Map.keys() call.

Comment: You mean "positive integer" or non-negative integers? The array contains IDs, so I don't need negative integers.  @Redu

Comment: What kind of assumptions can we make about the data?  For example, _is the data sorted_?

Comment: What do you mean with 'the array to be sorted'? If you sort your array anyways, you can remove duplicates in O(n) *without* hashmap

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is it;

```js
var myArray = [100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200],
    unified = Object.keys(myArray.reduce(function(p,c) {p[c] = true; return p;},{}));
console.log(unified);
```

Comment: But reduce is calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that that `lodash.uniq()` is faster then using `new Set()`

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/3889/0/lodash-uniq-vs-set

You can fork the test and add your own test cases.